# JSON Schema: combining unevaluatedProperties and $ref: #

Tags: jsonschema

In JSON Schema, I would like to define a property which allows as its contents anything from the root schema, *plus* one extra property.

For example, say I have a simple schema defining one property that is required, `reqProp`, so this is valid:

```
{
    "reqProp": "blah"
}
```

and another property `recursiveProp` which can contain anything from the root schema plus a new property `newProp`. So this would be valid:

```
{
    "reqProp": "blah",
    "recursiveProp": {
        "reqProp": "blah",
        "newProp": "foo"
    }
}
```

I have tried to combine [recursion](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref) and [unevaluated properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties) to make it work. This is what I came up with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "minimal-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Schema for testing recursive references with new properties",
  "description": "",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["reqProp"],
  "properties": {
    "reqProp": {
      "title": "Test required property",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "recursiveProp": {
      "title": "Test recursive property",
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
          "newProp": {
            "title": "New property that only exists as part of recursiveProp",
            "type": "string"
          }
      },
      "required": ["newProp"],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

But it fails:

```
% check-jsonschema --schemafile minimal-schema.json test2.json
Schema validation errors were encountered.
  test2.json::$.recursiveProp: Additional properties are not allowed ('newProp' was unexpected)
  test2.json::$.recursiveProp: Unevaluated properties are not allowed ('reqProp' was unexpected)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not possible with the 2020-12 draft?

Comment: This question has been answered at https://github.com/orgs/json-schema-org/discussions/375#discussioncomment-5595812

Comment: And thankyou very much for that. If you re-post it here I would be happy to mark it as the correct answer!